# Normalizable, but singular distribution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, singularities, normalization

I have obtained a probability distribution for the observable $l$ which takes the form:

$$ \frac{dP}{dl}=\frac{(1-\sqrt{1-3l^{2}})^{2}}{l^{3}\sqrt{1-3l^{2}}}\exp\left[-\frac{4\pi}{9l^{2}}(1-3l^{2})^{3/2}+\frac{4\pi}{9l^{2}}\right]$$

where $P(l)$ is the probability that $l$ is between $0$ and $l$. This distribution is valid for $l\in\{0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\}$. It is normalizable because:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{dP}{dl}dl=constant$$

However, it is singular at the value $l=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. This is counterintuitive because a normalizable distribution means that the sum of probabilities can be normalized to $1$. However, the value $l=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ has infinite probability.

How is this consistent? Is this observed in any well known physical system? What can it mean about the behavior of this system?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the probability distribution (or: probability density) and the propability. The former is your function $p(l) = \textrm{d} P / \textrm{d} l$, we obtain by integrating over some range of $l$,
\begin{equation}
 P([a,b]) = \int_a^b \textrm{d}l\ p(l).
\end{equation}
I.e. it is only meaningful to talk about the probability associated with an interval and if the volume of that interval goes to zero, $\vert a - b \vert \to 0$, so does $P([a,b])$. And as you already noted, your $p(l)$ integrated over any finite region always gives a finite number (i.e. it is an integrable function).

To see why there is no divergence for $\vert a - b \vert \to 0$ with $b = 1/\sqrt{3}$ (in fact we are showing that $p(l)$ is integrable despite the divergence), we can investigate $p(l)\textrm{d}l$. Changing variables to $x = \sqrt{3}l \in [0,1]$ and then to $x = \sin \theta$ with $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
  p(l)\textrm{d}l = 3 \frac{(1-\cos\theta)^2}{\sin^3 \theta} \exp\left[ - \frac{4\pi}{3 \sin^2\theta}(\cos^{3/2}\theta - 1) \right] \textrm{d} \theta.
\end{equation}
This is manifestly finite as $\theta \to \pi/2$ (corresponding to $l = 1/\sqrt{3}$). Note that under the change of variables $\textrm{d}l = \textrm{d}x / \sqrt{3} = \cos\theta \textrm{d}\theta / \sqrt{3}$. This factor of $\cos\theta$ cancels the $\sqrt{1-3l^2} = \cos\theta$ in the denominator.

This shows that when considering intervals, the divergences of your probability distribution are unproplematic.

Appendix:
To see that the limit $\theta \to 0$ is also unproblematic, expand in the numerator, $(1- \cos\theta)^2 \to \theta^4/4$, and the denominator, $\sin^3\theta \to \theta^3$. This leaves a power of $\theta \to 0$. The exponential goes to $\exp(- \textrm{large}) \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and insightful response! I am still skeptical about the following. It seems that the probability distribution will give different results for different representations (different variables to express it). This does not seem to be plausible. What am I missing here? Thanks again!

Comment: In fact nothing has changed between the representations. The probability to find $l$ between $a$ and $b$ is the same as the probability to find $\theta$ between $\arcsin(\sqrt{3}a)$ and $\arcsin(\sqrt{3}b)$ (these are the limits for $\theta$ corresponding to $a$ and $b$).
To make sure this is the case one needs to take into account the $(\textrm{d}\theta/\textrm{d} l)$ factor in $\textrm{d}l = (\textrm{d}\theta/\textrm{d} l) \textrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: Or, in other words, the general formula for a change of variables of a probability density (of one variable) is $p(\theta) = p(l(\theta)) (\textrm{d}\theta/\textrm{d}l)$.